# How to get the type underlying std::complex<T> and use it in a class

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

I am writing a data processor, and would like to be able to perform real-to-real, and real-to-complex computations. The setup I have right now:

```cpp
// class to hold various data types
template <typename T>
class DataArray
{
public:
    DataArray(){};
    T *ptr;
};

// Processing configuration 
template <typename T>
class Config
{
public:
    Config(){};
    T var;
};

// The data processor itself, takes input, output array and the processing configuration
template <typename Tin, typename Tout>
class Process
{
public:
    DataArray<Tin> *in;
    DataArray<Tout> *out;
    Config<Tout> *config;

    Process(){};
    Process(DataArray<Tin> *in_, DataArray<Tout> *out_, Config<Tout> *config_)
    {
        in = in_;
        out = out_;
        config = config_;
    }
};
```

Currently, I can handle real-to-real processing as follows:

```cpp
int main()
{
    DataArray<int16_t> input;
    DataArray<float> output;
    Config<float> config;
    // real 2 real processing
    Process<int16_t, float> P1(&input, &output, &config); // works fine 
    return 0;
}
```

The problem I am facing is that when I want to do real-to-complex processing, I still need my `Config` to be in the underlying type of `std::complex<T>`. How can I change the `Process` class (or any other class) such that I can create a class `Process<int16_t, std::complex<float>>` that will know that it expects a `Config<float>`?

```cpp
int main()
{
    DataArray<int16_t> input;
    DataArray<std::complex<float>> output_complex;
    Config<float> config;

    // real 2 complex processing
    Process<int16_t, std::complex<float>> P2(&input, &output, &config); // Obviously does not work

    return 0;
}
```

**Follow up question**
Thanks to the Remy's answer, I can now get the type of std::complex in the class `Process`. If I have a namespace with templated functions, how would I obtain the underlying type in that function/namespace? The following works, but feels a bit clunky. This means that I have to repeat the line `using T = typename helper::value_type_of<Tout>::type;` in every kernel, am I right?

```
// namespace with computation kernels
namespace kernels
{
    // define ConfigType in the kernel namespace? 
    template <typename T>
    using ConfigType = Config<typename helper::value_type_of<T>::type>;

    template <typename Tin, typename Tout, bool IQ>
    void bfpw(ConfigType<Tout> *BFC, Tin *RF, Tout *BF)
    {
        // get type of Tout: std::complex<float> or float
        using T = typename helper::value_type_of<Tout>::type;
        T variable = BFC->var;
    }
}

template <typename Tin, typename Tout>
Process<Tin, Tout>::Process(DataArray<Tin> *in_, DataArray<Tout> *out_, ConfigType *config_)
{
    in = in_;
    out = out_;
    config = config_;

    kernels::bfpw<Tin, Tout, true>(config, in->ptr, out->ptr); // call the kernel
}
```

Comment: Read the [documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/complex).

Comment: Specialize `Process`, or use SFINAE, to make it use `complex::value_type` when `Tout` is a `complex`.

Comment: @RemyLebeau ah I see, modifying `Process` to `using T = typename Tout::value_type; Config<T> *config;` works, but breaks the real-to-real case. I just started reading on SFINAE, could you perhaps show how to use that in this case?

Comment: @PaulSanders no currently I have to use C++11.

Comment: @rinkert OK, then you need(ed) to add that tag (important! - it's how the site works).  Which I have now done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to define a helper template which `Process` can use to detect whether `Tout` is a `std::complex` or not, and if so then it can use `Tout`'s `value_type` member, otherwise it can use `Tout` as-is.

For example:

```
namespace helper {

    template<typename T>
    struct value_type_of {
        using type = T;
    };

    template<typename T>
    struct value_type_of<std::complex<T>> {
        using type = typename std::complex<T>::value_type;
        // or simply: using type = T;
    };
}

template <typename Tin, typename Tout>
class Process
{
public:
    using ConfigType = Config<typename helper::value_type_of<Tout>::type>;

    ...
    ConfigType *config;

    Process(){};
    Process(..., ConfigType *config_)
    {
        ...
        config = config_;
    }
};
```

[Online Demo](https://ideone.com/7jZiCY)

This way, `Process<..., float>` and `Process<..., std::complex<float>>` will both accept `Config<float>`.

Comment: Thank you thats very clear, awesome! I have a followup question about how to deduce the underlying type in separate functions, not class methods.

Comment: @rinkert "*I have a followup question*" - then you should post it as its own separate question (that refers to this question for background, if needed). It should not be an edit to this question, which has now been answered as originally asked. Only 1 question per post, please. This is a Q&A site, not a discussion forum.